# ASP.NET MVC jQuery validation: how to show one message for all required fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-javascript

I got many `[Required]` fields in my model.

And, in traditional MVC way, I will add `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` for each required textbox.

Then, if user doesn't type anything for 5 textboxes, 5 message will show up in the UI.

My question is: can I show **just one message** saying *Please fill mandatory fields* in the UI instead of showing the message everywhere like *Name is required*, *Address is required*...?

and I need this to be validate on Client Side, without post form back to server

Comment: not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935568/jquery-validation-show-validation-summary-during-eager-validation, going with Aaron's answer.

Comment: Not really - that was regarding client side validation with jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at `ValidationSummary` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationsummary(v=vs.108).aspx - *Returns an unordered list (ul element) of validation messages that are in the ModelStateDictionary object.* You can override the message like so:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Invalid form")
```

Source https://stackoverflow.com/a/4924494/201648

Comment: thanks, but I need it to be done on client side, without a post to the server.

Comment: Ah! I have just been hooking into my `$(#yourFormName).submit(...` event and using `return false` in the function to stop the submit (http://api.jquery.com/submit/) with custom jQuery, or using jQuery validators http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate. A method I like for validating a group of fields is to create a controller which eturns a JSON object and send an AJAX request from the page.http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/216439/Data-Validation-Using-Annotations-for-jQuery-Ajax. Also have a look at http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Html.ValidationSummary`:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please fill mandatory fields")
```

If you also want to include a list of property specific errors use:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Please fill mandatory fields")
```